# Overload ambiguity with std::function that takes an std::optional parameter

Tags: c++, c++17

Here is a simple example program:

```
using fn_string = function<void(const string&)>;
using fn_optional_string = function<void(const optional<string>&)>;

void foo(fn_string) { cout << "string" << endl; }
void foo(fn_optional_string) { cout << "optional string" << endl; }

int main()
{
    foo([&](const string&){ });
    foo([&](const optional<string>&){ }); // <-- ambiguous
    return 0;
}
```

It has 2 overloads for `foo()` -- one taking function with `string` parameter and another with `optional<string>`.

Why is 2nd call to `foo()` ambiguous?

Is there a simple way to fix it? Without casts?

**UPDATE**

The above was an overly simplified example of the following real world problem I am trying to solve, which is:

```
using delegate = variant<
    function<void()>,
    function<void(const string&)>,
    function<void(const optional<string>&)>
>;

struct foo
{
    void add_delegate(delegate fn) { fns.push_back(std::move(fn)); }
    vector<delegate> fns;
};

int main()
{
    foo bar;
    bar.add_delegate([&](){ });
    bar.add_delegate([&](const string&){ });
    bar.add_delegate([&](const optional<string>&){ }); // ERROR
    return 0;
}
```

The last call to `add_delegate` fails to compile, as it can't decide between `function<void(const string&)>` and `function<void(const optional<string>&)>`.

My understanding was that the issue had to do with overload resolution (hence my original example). What change should I make to `add_delegate` to permit it to accept all 3 versions of lambdas?

Complete example can be found on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a0a47702a718809).

Comment: Due to the nature of `std::function`'s conversion constructor, I would *always* be cautious of trying to overload based on its template parameter. Just give the two functions different names or use a tag type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out to be simpler than I expected. All I had to do was add the following overload to `struct foo`:

```
void add_delegate(fn_opt_val fn) { add_delegate(delegate{ std::move(fn) }); }
```

Here is complete code on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c97a6e710ad422a).

Answer (score 4):

A lambda is not a `std::function<>`.  A `std::function<R(Args...)>` is a type-erasure value type that can store any copyable object that is call-compatible with `R(Args...)`.

In one case above, `R` is `void` (which for a `std::function` means "I don't care what it returns), and `Args...` is `std::string`.  A callable object is call-compatible with this if you can call it with a `std::string` rvalue.

This is true of both `std::optional<std::string>` and `std::string`.

There is no special overload for "exact match" -- all that matters is, call compatible or not.

There are a few ways to handle this.

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct overload_order : overload_order<N-1> {};
template<>
struct overload_order<0> {};

namespace details {
  void foo(overload_order<1>, fn_string) { cout << "string" << endl; }
  void foo(overload_order<0>, fn_optional_string) { cout << "optional string" << endl; }
}
template<class F>
void foo(F&& f) {
  foo( overload_order<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<F>, fn_optional_string>{}>{}, std::forward<F>(f) );
}
```

now we first try the `fn_string` one, and only if that fails do we try `fn_optional_string`, unless the argument is already a `fn_optional_string`, in which case we dispatch directly to that overload.

Comment: Thank you @Yakk, but unfortunately there is too much boilerplate for such a (seemingly) simple thing.

Comment: @innocent then use two different function names: overloading is not always the correct answer.

Comment: In my real world program things are a bit more complicated (I am assigning lambdas to `std::variant<std::function<void()>, std::function<void(const std::string&)>, std::function<void(const std::optional<std::string>&)>>`) but thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @InnocentBystander If that was your question my answer would have been completely different.  I'd write `emplace_first(variant&, args&&...)` which would find the first alternative of `variant` that can be constructed with `args&&...`.  This is because your problem is fundamentally different; you cannot rewrite the `std::variant::operator=` in your real problem.

Comment: I've updated my question, as I believe the problem is fundamentally the same, but in my attempt at keeping things simple, I've over simplified it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Declare the argument specifically as a fun_optional_string.

I don't know what to type to keep the software from complaining about a code only answer, so here's a poem:

There is an old hack from Milpitas...
His motto, "No bug can defeat us." ...
His resolve never lapses ...
As he fires those synapses ...
Fueled by doughnuts, cold rice, and fajitas. ...

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

using fn_string = function<void(const string&)>;
using fn_optional_string = function<void(const optional<string>&)>;

void foo(fn_string) { cout << "string" << endl; }
void foo(fn_optional_string) { cout << "optional string" << endl; }

int main()
{
    foo([&](const string&){ });
    fn_optional_string g = [&](const optional<string>&) {};
    foo(g); // <-- not ambiguous
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Plus one for the poem. I had to type out "plus one" as the software wasn't letting me to simply type "+1 for the poem"

Comment: @InnocentBystander - It's auto-biographical.